# MySQL convert column datatype from VARCHAR to INT

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with a VARCHAR(25) column that I want to convert to INT.  All of the data in the column is either integer or blanks.  I have tried this command:

```
ALTER TABLE ip MODIFY isp INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
```

Unfortunately, since some of the existing rows are empty I get this error:

```
ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'isp' at row 2
```

Thanks for assistance.

Comment: You have existing records and no default value like 0, for example. It cannot put empty content for a number, said on short.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

before altering your table, try to update your values.

The goal is to set a '0' value in the fields where you have empty values (which can't be converted to int)

```
update ip
set isp = '0' where trim(coalesce(isp, '')) = '';
```

If isp was not nullable, you can remove the coalesce function.

```
update ip 
set isp = '0' where trim(isp) = '';
```