# Change datatype using java jdbc of MySQL table

Tags: java, jdbc, sqldatatypes, alter-table

How to change the datatype from `varchar` to `int` using JDBC connection with Java of a table in MySQL?

I tried to use the query:

```
Alter table table_name CHANGE 'col 1' 'col 1' int (5 );
```

The file I am importing using the import option has the values in varchar, but I only required integer values from that table. The values of the imported table are not in ordered but the integer values are useful for me.

When I used the alter query in the phpmyadmin it works absolutely fine, but when I tried to alter in jdbc it gives me the error:

```
Incorrect integer value: at 'col 1';
```

jdbc code was as:

```
try {
    Connection co=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/csv_db","root",null);
    String c= " ALTER TABLE tpf1 MODIFY `col 3` int(5)";  
    String t="Alter table table_name CHANGE 'col 1' 'col 1' int (5 );";
    Statement stmt=co.createStatement();

    stmt.executeUpdate(t);

} catch (SQLException ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex);
}
```

Edit

```
try {
    Connection co=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/csv_db","root",null);
    String c= " ALTER TABLE tpf1 MODIFY `col ` int(20)";  

    Statement stmt=co.createStatement();

    stmt.executeUpdate(t);

} catch (SQLException ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex);
}
```

The table screenshot is in the Photo:[image: MySQL TABLE]

This is actually a pdf file and converted it into .csv and imported to my database
And i only need integer values from the table not any other alphabets and symbol.
This code is only for one column and i need to alter all the three columns.So what should i do to get only integer values using jdbc? :| :)

Comment: Just fire another query. See think link for appropriate query. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784201/mysql-convert-column-datatype-from-varchar-to-int

Comment: Do you know how to change it all, or are you stuck with how to execute it with JDBC?

Comment: Instead of `'col 1'`, you need to use `\`col 1\``, although it might as well mean that `col 1` contains a value that is not convertible to an integer value.

Comment: or between two `[col 1]` right @MarkRotteveel

Comment: @YCF_L Does that work MySQL? I thought that was MS Access, SQL Server and Sybase specific.

Comment: oohh my god, you are right @MarkRotteveel i thought it work also in MySQL i'm sorry 

Comment: Ok.Thanks for the reply but no change was there by changing from 'col 1' to `col 1`. The error remains the same. And i like to add another information that the `col 1` contain the alphabets and integer as well like example : Subject, code , course ,1,2,3, 4. These values are in different rows respectively and i need only integer values :)

Answer (score 2):

Like @Mark Rotteveel said in comment, you have a problem in your Query so the name of your columns should be between two ``` `` ``` and not between two `''` or `""` this not work if your column name contain more then one part so to change the type of your column you should to use this :

```
//change column type
String query = "ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY `col 1` INT(5)";
Statement stmt = co.createStatement();
int rslt = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
```

To change the name or your column use this :

```
//change column name
query = "ALTER TABLE tablename CHANGE `old name` `new name` INT(5);";
stmt = co.createStatement();
rslt = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
```

so you can check if your query executed successfully like this :

```
if (rslt > 0) {
    System.out.println("Success");
} else {
    System.out.println("Failed");
}
```

**Note**

If you change the type this will change all the column, and set it to `0`

I suggest to avoid two use a name with two parts you can use col_name instead because this make a problem for example if you are using JPA.

**EDIT**

I try this piece of code and it work fine :

```
public class UpdateColumn {

    static String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static String DB_username = "root";
    static String DB_password = "password";
    static String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name";

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*read from the file*/
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            java.sql.Connection co = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_username, DB_password);
            //change column type
            String query = "ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY `c 1` INT(5);";
            Statement stmt = co.createStatement();
            int rslt = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
            System.out.println(rslt);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**MySQL**

```
create database db_name;

use db_name;

drop table t1;

create table tablename(
`c 1` varchar(5),
`c 2` int
);

INSERT INTO tablename values('java', 1);
INSERT INTO tablename values('mysql', 2);
```

Good luck.

Comment: Ok.Thanks for the reply but no change was there by changing from 'col 1' to `col 1`. The error remains the same. And i like to add another information that the `col 1` contain the alphabets and integer as well like example : Subject, code , course ,1,2,3, 4. These values are in different rows respectively and i need only integer values :)

Comment: what did you mean remain the same what you want to change exactly the type or the name @AshbirDhiman

Comment: @AshbirDhiman if your table already contain some values of type `varchar` then you can't change the type to int check my edit hope this can help you

Comment: Okkk. But when i execute this alter query on phpmyadmin then it gives me no error? Why? Is there not any way that i can execute this query @YCF_L sir...I need this to Change.. please suggest me something. :| :)

Comment: @AshbirDhiman if you want to change the name then this is not a problem, if you want to change the type, this can make a problem, so what you want to do, change the name or change the type?

Comment: I want to change the datatype like where its it other than integer value e.g alphabets or any other symbol. it set the value to zero .please give me answer it works on phpmyadmin but not in jdbc? @ YCL_L sir :)

Comment: @AshbirDhiman i edit my answer i post now all my code and SQL so i hope this work with you

Comment: Okkk i tried this code in my table but it's not working..the error comes that : `incorrect integer value:"course" in col 2 at row 1` but when i copied it to phpmyadmin its works correctly :( :( 

Comment: can you post what you tried please? the complete code?

Comment: Okk Sure! But how should the whole code? like by editing the question or by Sending it by comment? @YCF_L sir :)

Comment: I have edited my question as you said @YCF_L Sir! and also my table :)

Comment: ?? Please tell me how to change the change The datatype sir!!  :|

Answer (score 0):

```
statement.executeUpdate("ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name datatype");
```