# Laravel migration, column varchar to integer and keep data

Tags: laravel, migration

Actually, I have a table named "course" with a column "status" of type varchar with datas "validated" or "draft".

I need to convert the column to tinyInt type but transform all actually "validated" status to 1 and all "draft" to 0 with the new type.

It is possible ?

I try this :

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('course', function (Blueprint $table) {
            if (Schema::hasColumn('course', 'status')) {
                $table->tinyInteger('status')->change();
            }
        });

        Course::where('status', 'validated')->update(['status' => 1]);
        Course::where('status', 'draft')->update(['status' => 0]);
    }
```

But the problem is when i put new values 0 and 1, the column type is already change.

Anyone know how to do this ?

**Update**

I tried this :

```
public function up()
    {
        // Rename status to old_status, and create a new other status column
        if (Schema::hasColumn('course', 'status')) {
            Schema::table('course', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->renameColumn('status', 'old_status');
                $table->tinyInteger('status');
            });
        }

        Course::where('old_status', 'validated')->update(['status' => 1]);
        Course::where('old_status', 'draft')->update(['status' => 0]);

        // Drop the old_status column
        Schema::table('course', function (Blueprint $table) {
            if (Schema::hasColumn('course', 'old_status')) {
                $table->dropColumn('old_status');
            }
        });
    }
```

But i get this error :

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'old_status' in
> 'where clause' (SQL: update `courses` set `status` = 2,
> `courses`.`updated_at` = 2021-08-05 05:23:48 where `old_status` =
> classroom and `courses`.`deleted_at` is null)

Comment: I think you can rename the status to old_status and add the new tinyint column status, then populate it, and finally drop the old_status

Comment: Or as it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784201/mysql-convert-column-datatype-from-varchar-to-int), you can do the update first and then convert the column, but it can be more risky